# Humans lose an interstellar war against humorous-looking aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, warfare

This is from an anthology, possibly from the 1950s.

The ambassador/general is delegated to a prisoner exchange on an isolated planet.

From the illustrations I recall the aliens look like short fat chess pieces.

Earth had tried to find allies with other species to help them in the war against these aggressors. They were rudely rebuffed by all of these aliens.
The aggressor aliens have a weapon that instantly vaporises the human ships, and that is why we have lost the war.

The exchange takes place, and it instantly becomes apparent why no-one else would help us.

The alien weapon is called a 'taker' and has simply stored the human ships in an alternate universe/location until returned.

All of the human losses are returned, and the aliens promise to give the taker technology to the humans, as they say we 'play too hard' without it.

Update: No-one else would help us because it would have been considered as cheating.

Comment: "The exchange takes place, and it instantly becomes apparent why no-one else would help us".  Can you add to this please?

Comment: "Honorable Opponent" by Clifford Simak, which you can read here: https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1956-08/page/n37/mode/2up If you agree, we can close this question as a duplicate, as I'm pretty sure this has been answered before.

Comment: You might have read it in one of these: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?45919

Comment: Thanks for finding this for me. user14111 continues to astonish and impress.